# Function Pattern matching: Scala - lost in initial call

Tags: scala, recursion, pattern-matching

I am trying to understand a Scala Pattern Matching function and I can't seem to wrap my head around what is going on here.

```
sealed abstract class SearchTree
  case object Empty extends SearchTree
  case class Node(l: SearchTree, d: Int, r: SearchTree) extends SearchTree

  def test(t: SearchTree): Boolean = {
    def check(t: SearchTree, min: Int, max: Int): Boolean = t match {
      case Empty => true
      case Node(l, d, r) =>  min <= d && d < max && check(l, min, d) && check(r, d, max)
    check(t, Int.MinValue, Int.MaxValue)
  }
```

My question is: where are the values min: Int, max: Int being passed through with the initial match call? After that I understand the successive recursive calls but how can we begin the pattern match with only t:SearchTree as a known value.

I do have tests for this function but I do not believe they are necessary for the question

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`min` and `max` are passed in via the call to `check` at the the of the function `test` with this call `check(t, Int.MinValue, Int.MaxValue)`. So all `test` does is call `check` with `t`, `Int.MinValue` and `Int.maxValue`. `min` and `max` aren't passed through the initial `match` call they are in scope and thus accessible in the case statements.

Comment: That is what I thought but where is the Int.MinValue, Int.MaxValue coming from?

is it the t.minValue and t.Maxvalue? Basically what is Int in this case?

Comment: `Int` is imported automatically via `scala.Predef`. It's a pre-defined integer class available to use.

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to understand but not entirely... What would be the  hypothetical values of the Int.Max(Min)Value. I still don't understand how a value is initially assigned to these variables. Thanks for baring with me.

Comment: `Int.MaxValue` returns the maximum integer that can be represented which is `2147483647`. `Int.MinValue` returns `-2147483648
`. Enter these in the REPL to see. So, the value `2147483647` is passed to `max` when `check` is called and similarly for `min`.